# Exception: The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, shap

I am dealing with a Regression problem and I used [StackingRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingRegressor.html) to train data and then make prediction on test set. For model explainability purpose, I used [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) as follows:

```
import xgboost
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor
import shap

# train a model
X, y = shap.datasets.boston()
stkr = StackingRegressor(
estimators = [('xgbr', xgboost.XGBRegressor()), ('rfr', RandomForestRegressor())],
final_estimator = xgboost.XGBRegressor(),
cv = 3
)
 
model = stkr.fit(X, y)

explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer(X)
shap.summary_plot(explainer(X), X)
```

After running this code, I face with the following error:

```
Exception: The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: StackingRegressor
```

I have no idea why I got `The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: StackingRegressor` error, while I could use the same code and replace `StackingRegressor` with `RandomForestRegressor` or `XGBoostRegressor` and run it without any problem.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue with a different model. The solution that worked for me was to use [KernelExplainer](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.KernelExplainer.html) instead of [explainer](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.Explainer.html). Additionally you need to use the model.predict function instead of just the model. Note that to get the shaps values you need to use KernelExplainer.shap_values() uses a function

So I think this should work:

```
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model.predict, X)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train, plot_type="bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of shap are you using?
I just found this error and fixed it by upgrading the version from 0.39.0 to 0.40.0

Not sure can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and found out that some models are not supported by SHAP, what worked for me is much simpler, replacing

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
```

with:

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model.predict)
```

You can read this issue for more details to understand the difference between `model` and `model.predict` [What is the correct way to obtain explanations for predictions using Shap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73568255/what-is-the-correct-way-to-obtain-explanations-for-predictions-using-shap)

Comment: Probably this issue can be directly linked to the one I'm mentioning above